# jquery validation messages: how to customize the message with a response via php

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am creating a multi-language website. I need that messages are not written into the script as constants in jQuery. I tried to solve this:

```
$("#frmLogin").validate
({
    rules: 
    {
        'userName': { required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        regex:  "^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\\s]{5,40}$"},
        'passWord': { required: true,
        minlength: 5,}
    },
    messages:
    {
        'userName':{ 
            required:$.post("ajaxError.php",{ error:27,rand:Math.random()},function(data)
            { 
                if(JSON.parse(data)[0]=='') 
                {
                    error= 'Error not found';
                }else{
                    error= JSON.parse(data)[0];
                }
                return error;
            })),
```

etc.

The error variable contains the correct message but it is not intercepted by jquery.message.

Comment: Can't you just query for the error message before the `validate` call?

Comment: Yes, I solved by creating a variable. I also had to use the ajax method (instead of post / get) to set up synchronization. myVar=$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajaxError.php",
    data: "error=27",
    success: function(response){},
        async: false
    });

Comment: Instead of using `async: false`, you should consider just initializing the validate plugin inside of your success callback. `async: false` will block the user from interacting with the browser while your request is in progress.